# D3 data sort order

Tags: d3.js

I have a multiline graph that has the data sorted by date first and then PFC ID (the data being graphed).  The line chart itself works fine, but I am also dynamically creating the legend and the legend is being sorted by date first and then the PFC ID.  I'd rather just have the legend itself sorted by PFC ID without the date.  Is there a way I can do this without messing up the chart?  If I remove the primary sort on the date from the query the chart itself no longer works correctly.

The code for the legend is below:

```
    legend.append("rect")
    .attr("height",10)
    .attr("width", 25)
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.key; })
    .attr("x", width + 30)
    .attr("y", function(d,i) { return height - 495 + (i*25); })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key);})
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

An example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/goodspeedj/5ewLxpre/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort the data after your nest call:

```
        // nest data
        var nested_data = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) { return dimKey(d); })
            .entries(data);

        // sort on key
        nested_data.sort(function(a,b){
          return a.key.localeCompare(b.key);
        });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ewLxpre/11/).

**FOR COMMENTS**

Assuming `wellID` is uniquely paired to `wellName`, then it's:

```
        nested_data.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.values[0].wellID - b.values[0].wellID;
        });
```

Update [fiddle two.](https://jsfiddle.net/nhk5mufr/13/)

Comment: This is close, but I'd actually want to sort on the ID (the primary key) which is not a key - it is one of the values.  I'm reading through the D3 docs on nesting and sorting now.

Comment: @JamesE, what property represents the `ID`?  Your data only has 3 properties, `shortName` (which is key in the nest), `sampleDate` or `pfcLevel`.

Comment: my apologies the Fiddle had an old dataset in it.  I have updated it - the property is chemID.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, either the fiddle above should now have the chemID in it.  If you can't get to that one this one should also work: https://jsfiddle.net/goodspeedj/nhk5mufr/ but instead of chemID the value I would want to sort on would be wellID.